# Dictionary with marginal references

Tags: cross-referencing, marginpar, sorting, dictionaries

I follow a mathematica course with a lot of definitions. I want to make a list of those definitions. However sometimes terms refer to each other. To make the list more usable to read it would be nice if there was a command so I can refere to other elements in the "dictionary". I've seen this in the books of Donald Knuth as footnotes. But don't know a good package to make an elegant dictionary. Automatic alphabetical sorting of the entries would also be a nice feature.

Comment: Your question isn't fully clear to me. You also mention "marginal" in the title but not in the text. If you want this references as `marginpar`s you should explicitly say so. However, then it might be better to split it into two different questions.

Comment: You could create a glossary using the `glossaries` package (there was recently a question about that, but I can't find it just now). But I'm not sure if you can `\label` and `\ref` between glossaries texts.

Comment: I mean the reference in the explanation don't directly refer to another page. But in the margin, the references are repeated with the page where the description of that item is. @Martin: I've taken a look to the glossaries package but it doesn't seem to handle references at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the purpose of the Index:

```
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

...

The term \emph{sarsaparilla}\index{sarsaparilla} denotes ...
```

You have to run `makeindex` and the Index will contain the word and the page number for reference. If you need also to repeat something in the margin, define a couple of commands:

```
\newcommand{\defineterm}[1]{\emph{#1}\index{#1}\label{term@#1}}
\newcommand{\useterm}[1]{#1\marginpar{#1, see p.~\pageref{term@#1}}}

...

The term \defineterm{sarsaparilla} denotes ...

...

... and now we employ \useterm{sarsaparilla} to ...
```

If you don't really need the index, just comment out the `\makeindex` command.